# Use property transfer in the API request of another test step

Tags: api, soapui, web-api-testing

I am using soapUI open source version to test an API. am using a token to access the test step.
I need to send the token with the API request.I have transferred the token value to the test step using property transfer but the transferred value is embedded in the body of the next request.
I want to send the value as a query parameter along with API request/

API Structure : Post method
api/v1/delete/token

the transferred value should be sent in place of token.

Kindly assist me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your second request as a correct resource, and parametrize the token variable. Official [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/understanding-rest-parameters.html) is available.

After that, you do not need to use a transfer step for something this simple. You can just use property expansion, as per official [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html). Something like: `${previous_step_name#ResponseAsXml#//*:token}`

Comment: Am new to soapui and groovy scripting,can u kindly elaborate your suggestion

Comment: @Vittal SO is not the right medium; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Start here: http://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/getting-started.html